# CSS3 filters, transition not working on IE and Safari

Tags: html, css

As you can in my snippet when you run, I have a box and underneath that I have a sort of shadow which slow gets bigger if I hover over the box.

```css
.container{
      min-height: 400px;
   overflow: auto;
   clear: both;
  background: red;
}
.content {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 441px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.content:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 7px;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 228px;
    height: 48px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-filter: blur(25px);
    -o-filter: blur(25px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 0.3);
    -o-transform: scale(1, 0.3);
}

.content:hover:after {
    width: 350px;
    height: 80px;
    transition: all .8s;
    -webkit-transition: all .8s;
    -o-transition: all .8s;
    -moz-transition: all .8s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Find Your</h3>
    <div class="main_content">
      <h3>Nearest</h3>
      <p>Fryking</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make this work on all browsers?
At the moment I only see it on chrome and firefox. When I go to IE and Safari my code does not work.

This is how it looks on chrome:

[image]

And here how it looks on safari and IE:

[image]

Hope you can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the MDN website it says that IE currently has no support for filter CSS property and unluckily I can't see a way to fix this.
[MDN css filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

However there are 2 alternatives

1. Use a picture with transparency (like .png) of a circle gradient. You would need to create it in some kind of software like Adobe Photoshop or find online. 
   Then you could use it as a background-image in your CSS.
2. Use the radial-gradient for the background in CSS. (There are lots of websites for generating it)
   Should work for:

   background: radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0))

(Requires -o- -moz- -webkit- for support in different browsers)

Finally set backgroud-size: 100% 100%